# How to edit a list item inline using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I have a text field,button and ul. User enters email in the textfield and clicks a buttons to make an AJAX call. If the email has any user in the database, then it updates the ul->li. I want to provide user with an opportunity to edit the data in ul->li. I am unable to do so.  Do you have any ideas on how I can do this?

```
#tasks-add= Button
#foo= textfield
#tasks= ul

<script>(This script to make Ajax call and update ul)
                  $("#tasks-add").click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                  success: function(html){
                  $(".tasks").prepend(html);
                  },
                  type: 'post',
                  url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('field')?>',
                  data: {
                  index:$("#foo").val(),index1: $(".tasks li").size()
                  },
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: 'html'
                  })
              });


               </script>


     <script> (this script to in line edit ul using jeditable)
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.tasks li').editable('http://www.google.com');
 });
</script> 



              <ul class="tasks">

***// this is what I am updating through Ajax. I want inline edit to be performed here***

               </ul>


<><><><><><><>><><>><><><><><><><><><><>

_task.php

**<li>
    <div class="panel">
                <?php if($check=='Player already existed'){
                    echo $index1.". ".$fname ." ".$lname;
                    echo "<label> Player already existed</label>";

                } else
                echo "<label> New Player will be added</label>";
                ?>
</div>
</li>**
```